# ArrayList not updating

Tags: android, sqlite, parsing, arraylist

I try to update the ArrayList to display it in the Listview from my SQLite database but the list shows up empty. The SQLite works fine because the data shows up in the logs but is not added in the list.

One thing I want to add is that I have also linked this list with Parse to get data online and save it in my Database for offline availability.

**The list updates fine when it fetches data from Parse.**

```
public void listUpdater () {

    Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user", null);

    int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");

    titles.clear();

    if (c.moveToFirst()){

        do {

            Log.i("RESULT: ",c.getString(titleIndex));

            titles.add(c.getString(titleIndex));




        } while (c.moveToNext());


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

}
```

Here is the method call for the data

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);


        myDB = openOrCreateDatabase("Users", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(title VARCHAR)");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, titles);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listUsers);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listUpdater();

        titles.clear();

// After this the list is updated from Parse

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `AsyncTask` for this problem. Fetch the data from your database in `doInBackground()` and update the UI/list in `onPostExecute()`.

For more information or examples check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problems. But why did it not call my method properly?

Comment: I think it's because the `onCreate()`. The UI was not create at the time you wanted to update the UI. So first create UI, then fetch data (async so there is no freeze -> you can show loading dialog or something like that), then update UI ;)

Answer (score 0):

first of all.. why would you need to set the adapter before you fetch the data. You could do something like this.

1. show a loading dialog.
2. fetch the data from db or online/json
3. parse it.
4. initialize the adapter
5. set the adapter to the view.
6. in case you need to update the list. do a notifyItemChanged(fromPos, list.size());

hope that helps

Comment: I want to add my data offline as well so when the internet connection is not available users can still view their previously loaded data. Do tell me if there is a workaround for this in my case. Thanks

Comment: Yes.. you can do so as well. In that case use asynctask, if you want to give the user freedom to do whatever they want while you prepare your data.